# When and how did classical mythology subjects start to appear in art in medieval/Renaissance Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, renaissance, greek-mythology

All early medieval Europe art objects I am aware of are either about the Christian subjects or about the history (chronicles etc.). Classical mythology was obviously known in Europe before, see e.g. [What did people in 13th century England know about Greek mythology?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42297/) , but it was not seen in the art (as far as I am aware) until the 15th century.

Then, sometime in the 15th century, we see the emergence of art objects (drawings, tapestries, etc.) showing antique mythology subjects, e.g. [this drawing made by Jacopo Bellini in cr. 1420-1470](https://www.photo.rmn.fr/archive/83-001050-2C6NU0O70022.html).

When and, if known, why has antique mythology re-emerged in art? Was it because new knowledge has emerged or some restrictions have been abolished?

One of the possibilities is emerging archaeology (Ciriaco de' Pizzicolli, 1391 – 1453/55, has pioneered it in Europe), but there might be other reasons.

Comment: What do you mean by "*widely known*"? Nobility? Educated elite? Middle Class (much of which we might regard today as premier blue-collar workers, such as stone masons and cabinet makers, running their own shops)? Peasants? Other?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I meant nobility or educated elite, but happy to take the answer with any reasonable interpretation of "widely known".

Comment: The premise is flawed; Europeans never stopped knowing about pagan mythology. While an ostensibly different question, I think the answers here also answers your query: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42297/what-did-people-in-13th-century-england-know-about-greek-mythology

Comment: [This article](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780195397703/student/materials/myth_art/) suggests that astrology was a key area where knowledge of classical mythology was maintained in Western Europe.

Comment: Mark  C. Wallace, @Semaphore - thanks, this is indeed a better question. I have wrongly assumed that the mythology was not known since it was not depicted. Should I do an edit, leave as is or delete this question and ask a new one?

Comment: @YuliaV - IMHO, you should revise the question to elict what you really want to know.  (and then flag obsolete comments for deletion).

Comment: Anyone who has read any Chaucer will see how familiar he is with Greek and Roman mythology, and how expected his readers to be.

Answer (score 5):

[This short essay](https://d33c33.wordpress.com/yet-more-old-stuff/mythology-and-ideology-in-italian-renaissance-art/) called "Mythology and Ideology in Italian Renaissance Art" is quite relevant. The key idea is that in the prosperous city-states of Italy, "[Neoplatonist ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonism_in_the_Renaissance) were translated into allegorical and symbolic images: images drawn from pre-Christian mythology, and interpreted as symbols for concepts acceptable to Renaissance Christians."

However, according to the Wikipedia article on [the Italian Renaissance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Renaissance):

> There has been much debate as to the degree of secularism in the Renaissance, which had been emphasized by early 20th-century writers like Jacob Burckhardt based on, among other things, the presence of **a relatively small number of mythological paintings**. Those of Botticelli, notably [The Birth of Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth_of_Venus) and Primavera, are now among the best known, although he was deeply religious (becoming a follower of Savonarola) and the great majority of his output was of traditional religious paintings or portraits

Regarding ***The Birth of Venus*** Wikipedia further mentions:

> As depictions of subjects from classical mythology on a very large scale they were **virtually unprecedented in Western art since classical antiquity**, as was the size and prominence of a nude female figure in the Birth. It used to be thought that they were both commissioned by the same member of the Medici family, but this is now uncertain.
>
> They have been endlessly analysed by art historians, with the main themes being: the emulation of ancient painters and the context of wedding celebrations (generally agreed), the influence of Renaissance Neo-Platonism (somewhat controversial), and the identity of the commissioners (not agreed).

Comment: Thank you, but could you bridge the gap of 40 years between the Council of Florence of  1439 when Platonic philosophy was popularized in Renaissance Italy, and Boticelli's Venus. I don't mind the size, maybe smaller works to show the progress?

Comment: This tapestry, a pretty big one, was made in ct. 1475, some 10 years earlier than Venus https://art.thewalters.org/detail/610/